# How to pass parameter dynamic without class in codeigniter like www.example.com/myname1 or myname2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to pass parameter in codeigniter like facebook

```
http://www.facebook.com/php
```

or

```
http://www.facebook.com/codeigniter
```

I want dynamic parameter seting like facebook

example :

```
www.example.com/php
```

or

```
www.example.com/codeigniter
```

and particular class will load profile page with dynamic parameter

Comment: i haven't try any thing, but i have confusion what i have to implement class for something else..

Comment: Is [creating static pages tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html) something you ask? Please clarify your question more, try something with code and post error message (editting question) if any.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what are you looking for?
In `config/routes.php`:

```
$routes['default_controller'] = 'main_controller/redirect';
$routes['(:any)'] = 'main_controller/redirect';
```

in `controllers/main_controller`:

```
class Main_controller extends CI_Controller{

   public function redirect(){
       switch($this->uri->segment(1)){
          case 'codeigniter':
             return $this->page_codeigniter();
             break;
          default:
             return $this->main_page();
             break;
       }
   }

   public function page_codeigniter(){

       // ... your code and load view  

   }

}
```